# ¿Cómo corregir el error Unknown constraint direction found al usar el método lp?

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy intentando resolver un problema de programación lineal,he intentando multiples de solcionar el siguiente error, pero no me ha sido posible,

> Unknown constraint
> direction found.

```
#         Proteína animal(x1)  Proteína vegetal(x2)
#                2.5                   1
#                1                     2

#  z= min 18000x1+ 31200x2

#               Restricciones

# 2.5x1 + x2 =>
#    x1 +2x2 =>
# x1,x2=>0
library(lpSolve)

funcion_objetivo <- c(18000,31200)
restricciones_derecho <- matrix(c(2.5,1,1,2), nrow = 2, byrow = 2 )
restriccion.direcion <- c("=>", "=>","=>") #vector de direcciones de las desigualdades
lado_derecho.restricion <- c(3,4)

#La solucion la buscamos con la funcion lp()
lp(direction = "min", objective.in = funcion_objetivo,
   const.mat = restricciones_derecho,
   const.dir=restriccion.direcion, const.rhs = lado_derecho.restricion,
   int.vec = c(1,2,3,4), all.int=T)
```